# Как заставить работать отладчик в EPIC под Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, perl

Понадобилось разбираться в довольно сложной программе на Perl. Для решения этой задачи я поставил EPIC, но не могу добиться нормальной работы отладчика. Он минимально помогает редактировать (зачаточная автоподстановка и подсветка синтаксиса (правда, глюкастенькая - любой слэш принимает за начало регекспа)), [image: кривая подсветка синтаксиса]
позволяет выполнять программу, но отладчик практически не работает.

По кнопке F11 (debug), F5 и А6 он пошагово выполняет программу и показывает номер строки (видно в вьюшке debug), но не показывает текущую инструкцию в редакторе (не позиционирует текст в редакторе на нее и никак не выделяет; для сравнения - справа Java остановилось в точке останова, стрелочка и зеленая полоска показывают текущую инструкцию);

[image: По кнопке F11 (debug) выполняется инструкция в строке 25, но редактор на нее не позиционируется и никак ее не подсвечивает]

точки останова игнорирует(по команде resume(F8) выполняет код до конца, без остановок в точках останова);

Как посмотреть содержимое переменных - непонятно, watch показывает error: `watch expressions not supported`, да и мало толку от просмотра переменных, когда не работают точки останова. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До сего дня отлаживался просто выводом на консоль, но уже утомило.

Штатную инструкцию (http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06.php) прочитал, много разных танцев с бубнами нагугливается, некоторые (показавшиеся наиболее релевантными) пробовал - безуспешно, а пробовать их все - жизни не хватит. 
Не знает ли кто-нибудь внятного траблошутера по отладке под EPIC, или может быть, кто-то может поделиться соображениями или опытом?

О себе: Windows server 2003 x64, Eclipse 4.2.1 (Mars), Perl v5.24 в комплектации Strawberry.

PadWalker установлен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но может быть, как-то неправильно установлен? Не в той директории, где-то в пути не прописан? Не знаю, что и как проверить.

В Perl'e не силен, про его библиотеки и модули почти ничего не знаю - и хотелось бы сильно не вникать - это не основная моя работа.

Comment: Проверьте, стоит ли в системе модуль PadWalker: https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker

Comment: @PinkTux стоит. 
    `X:\>cpanm PadWalker`
    `PadWalker is up to date. (2.2)`

Answer (score 0):

Установите модуль PadWalker (http://search.cpan.org/~robin/PadWalker-2.2/PadWalker.pm), это должно помочь с нализом переменных.

Comment: PadWalker у меня стоит, и содержимое переменных при пошаговом выполнении я вижу (я был неправ в первоначальной формулировке вопроса), но невозможно же пошагово добратся до конца программы в 5000 строк с многчисленными и многуровневыми циклами... Все остальное - выражения, точки останова и подсветка текущей инструкции - так и не работает.